# Bootstrap Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make it so that with the "Horses" tab in my NavBar, a drop down menu appears when I hover over it or click on it. I want the drop down for the "Horses" tab to have an unordered list with "foals," "mares," and "stallions" inside of it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>VS Equine - European Sport Horses</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="brand">VS Equine</div>
<div class="address-bar">Viksbergs Sateri | Sodertalje, Sweden | +46-70 699 67 40</div>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">VS Equine</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="blog.html">Horses</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="USedition.html">US Edition</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h2 class="brand-before">
                    <small>Welcome to</small>
                </h2>
                <h1 class="brand-name">VS Equine</h1>
                <hr class="tagline-divider">
                <h2>
                        <strong>European Sport Horses</strong>
                    </small>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">We don't just breed horses
                    <strong>We raise champions!</strong>
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <img class="img-responsive img-border img-left" src="img/intro-pic.jpg" alt="">
                <hr class="visible-xs">
                <p>Viksbergs Säteri driver en liten familjeuppfödning med bara några få föl som föds varje år, i regel inte mer än 5. Vårt syfte med varje föl är att det skall bli en svårklasshäst som tävlar om de stora priserna i framtiden. </p>
                <p>Vi sysslar inte med massuppfödning! Vi är djupt specialiserade på hopphästar av den högsta kalibern. Vi använder därför enbart ston som antingen har visat sig ge fantastiska avkommor tidigare eller som själva har visat att de är av yppersta klass, helst både och.</p>
                <p>Vi bygger på lång sikt och hållbarhet är ett av våra ledord. På det viset skapar vi hästar som har stor kapacitet, har tillit till sin ryttare, håller på lång sikt och gör det där extra för sin ryttare som är helt avgörande i de stora klasserna. Många elitryttare kan intyga att just kopplingen mellan ryttaren (människan) och hästen är helt avgörande för resultatet. Vi tror att det är detta som skapar Champions som håller på lång sikt!.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">VS Equine
                    <strong>and partners</strong>
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Vi samarbetar med andra företag i hästbranchen – både i Sverige och utomlands. Vi ställer samma krav på dem som vi ställer på oss själva. Ärlighet, Öppenhet, Hållbarhet och Kvalitet är våra ledord. För att arbeta väl tillsammans behöver även våra samarbetspartners ha samma värdegrund som vi själva har. </p>
                <p>Vårt samarbete med andra gör att vi ofta kan finna den specifika häst som en potentiell kund söker, även om vi inte har en sådan själv. Vi har möjlighet att före köpet ge hästen den speciella träning som behövs för att den skall passa sin nya ryttare. Om du funderar på att köpa en ny häst ställ därför gärna en förfrågan till oss på: info@VS-equine.eu.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <p>Copyright &copy; VS Equine 2015</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have Bootstrap being included correctly? E.g. via the include in your HTML? Would you be able to provide that part of the code if so...

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have the full markup for a drop down navigation element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a dropdown, you first will need the markup to do so as listed [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

The markup should look like this (Were also going to add an id to setup the hover functionality):

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="hover-drop">Horses <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Foals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mares</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stallions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Now for the javascript, it will grab the element that we created, to track when we hover (Lets also surround the code in a initializer so that it won't start until all the query elements have finished and the document is ready):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })

    $('#hover-drop').hover(function() {                  
      $(this).dropdown('toggle');
    });
  });
</script>
```

So then the whole page would look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>VS Equine - European Sport Horses</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="brand">VS Equine</div>
<div class="address-bar">Viksbergs Sateri | Sodertalje, Sweden | +46-70 699 67 40</div>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">VS Equine</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="hover-drop">Horses <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Foals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mares</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stallions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="USedition.html">US Edition</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h2 class="brand-before">
                    <small>Welcome to</small>
                </h2>
                <h1 class="brand-name">VS Equine</h1>
                <hr class="tagline-divider">
                <h2>
                        <strong>European Sport Horses</strong>
                    </small>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">We don't just breed horses
                    <strong>We raise champions!</strong>
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <img class="img-responsive img-border img-left" src="img/intro-pic.jpg" alt="">
                <hr class="visible-xs">
                <p>Viksbergs Säteri driver en liten familjeuppfödning med bara några få föl som föds varje år, i regel inte mer än 5. Vårt syfte med varje föl är att det skall bli en svårklasshäst som tävlar om de stora priserna i framtiden. </p>
                <p>Vi sysslar inte med massuppfödning! Vi är djupt specialiserade på hopphästar av den högsta kalibern. Vi använder därför enbart ston som antingen har visat sig ge fantastiska avkommor tidigare eller som själva har visat att de är av yppersta klass, helst både och.</p>
                <p>Vi bygger på lång sikt och hållbarhet är ett av våra ledord. På det viset skapar vi hästar som har stor kapacitet, har tillit till sin ryttare, håller på lång sikt och gör det där extra för sin ryttare som är helt avgörande i de stora klasserna. Många elitryttare kan intyga att just kopplingen mellan ryttaren (människan) och hästen är helt avgörande för resultatet. Vi tror att det är detta som skapar Champions som håller på lång sikt!.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">VS Equine
                    <strong>and partners</strong>
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Vi samarbetar med andra företag i hästbranchen – både i Sverige och utomlands. Vi ställer samma krav på dem som vi ställer på oss själva. Ärlighet, Öppenhet, Hållbarhet och Kvalitet är våra ledord. För att arbeta väl tillsammans behöver även våra samarbetspartners ha samma värdegrund som vi själva har. </p>
                <p>Vårt samarbete med andra gör att vi ofta kan finna den specifika häst som en potentiell kund söker, även om vi inte har en sådan själv. Vi har möjlighet att före köpet ge hästen den speciella träning som behövs för att den skall passa sin nya ryttare. Om du funderar på att köpa en ny häst ställ därför gärna en förfrågan till oss på: info@VS-equine.eu.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <p>Copyright &copy; VS Equine 2015</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel And add hover -->
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 5000 //changes the speed
        });

        $('#hover-drop').hover(function() {                  
          $(this).dropdown('toggle');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, properly formatting your code in the questions will also help in noticing what is wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty new to StackOverflow and cannot "upvote" your answer otherwise you know I'd be upvoting that answer all day long!

Comment: So I just tried to implement the changes and the menu still isn't dropping down when I hover on the "horses" tab. Any other ideas?

Comment: What version. Of jquery and bootstrap are you using? Also can you show me the end of your java script as well as the whole document?

Comment: Can I email you the zip file?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm not finding it. Could you shoot me an email and I'll reply with the zip file? My email is 19rjh91@gmail.com... Thank you so much, again I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Jonathan, if you have a minute, I could really use your help. I sent you an email, thanks again for everything.

Comment: Sure can. I'll check my email now. But I'm currently out with the family.